# Problem with installation of LUBUNTU

Tags: dual-boot

I have just installed Lubuntu on a laptop.  I was trying to install it alongside Windows and therefore chose the option for Local Volume control (I think that is correct) and expected that when I booted up I would be presented with a choice between Lubuntu and Windows.
But I am not getting a choice.  It goes straight into Lubuntu.

So have I lost my windows files forever or is there a way to get back in Windows and recover my files?
Thank you.
SJF

Answer (score 0):

You can always hold shift at the beginning of the booting process to access the GRUB menu. There should be other operating systems listed, if detected.

You can also try [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to fix boot problems and to rewrite your GRUB entries:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```